# Multiple NSURLSession dependent download tasks

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I wanted to learn some NSURLSession basics and I was wondering how to handle multiple requests from an API. Like if you ask for a user resource on Github's api, it has an avatar_url, and then wanted to use that avatar_url to make another request.  I have this so far:

```
let reposEndpoint = URL(string: "users/crystaltwix", relativeTo: baseURL)
        var reposRequest = URLRequest(url: reposEndpoint!)
        reposRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
            "content-type": "application/json"
        ]

        session?.dataTask(with: reposRequest) { data, response, error in
            guard let response = response, let data = data else {
                print("something went wrong")
                return
            }
            print("response: \(response)")
            //            print("data: \(data)")
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
                print(user)
                // avatar URL
                let avatarURL = URL(string: user.avatarURL)
                let avatarEndpoint = URLRequest(url: avatarURL!)
                self.session?.dataTask(with: avatarEndpoint) { data, response, error in
                    guard let response = response, let data = data else {
                        print("something went wrong inner")
                        return
                    }
                    let avatarImage = UIImage(data: data)
                    let userModel = UserModel(login: user.login, avatar: avatarImage!, name: user.name, bio: user.bio)
                }
            } catch let error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print(error)
                completion(nil, nil, error)
            }
        }.resume()

struct User: Codable {
    let login: String
    let avatarURL: String
    let name: String
    let bio: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case login
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
        case name
        case bio
    }
}
```

So the first request to the user works and I make my URLRequest with the `user.avatarURL` fine, but then in the next

```
self.session?.dataTask(with: avatarEndpoint) { // nothing happens here }
```

No request is made there. What's the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your code, i think you forgot to call resume method in second request.

```
self.session?.dataTask(with: avatarEndpoint) { data, response, error in
    guard let response = response, let data = data else {
         print("something went wrong inner")
          return
      }
      let avatarImage = UIImage(data: data)
      let userModel = UserModel(login: user.login, avatar: avatarImage!, name: user.name, bio: user.bio)
 }.resume()
```

resume method means start requesting.